# How to remove the small line below Appbar?

Tags: flutter

Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.8

There is a little thin line just below the Appbar. Do you know how to get rid of it?

[image]

Code:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              await _authService.signOut();
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.exit_to_app,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.blue),
);
```

Comment: I was tried your code but not getting any line as per you said,can you please share your full code?

Comment: @HardikTalaviya, just added the container code from the 'body'. By the way, I am on Android and directly on the device (not a simulator)

Comment: I also run your code in both the simulator and the device but there is no thin line below the AppBar.

Comment: @David Any solution for this one?

Answer (score 4):

Specify the scaffold backgroundColor to same color as your AppBar backgroundColor   will solve the issue (in your case the below code)
to give the rest of app the color you want you can have that in the body color of the container enclosing the body

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,//changed background color of scaffold
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    elevation: 0.0,
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await _authService.signOut();
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.exit_to_app,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.blue),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have added 1pt to appbar's height and the line gone.

```
AppBar(
    toolbarHeight: kToolbarHeight + 1,
    title: Text('Title'),
)
```

#### Update

Eventually, it comes up that the solution from above will not work well for all the screen, the line will disappear from one and become appear on the other one, so no other solution for now ))

Comment: In my case, I added 1.25 and now that line is gone. Any other value and the line becomes visible again.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for a proper solution, it seems this line is drawn by the `shape` property, so passing in a shape that doesn't draw anything seems to make this divider disappear.

E.g.

```
AppBar(
  shape: const LinearBorder(),
);
```

Works like a charm in my `SliverAppBar`, hopefully this helps someone else out too!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in web, iphone simulator, android simulator and my android phone, didnt get white thin line any of them. I am working on flutter beta right now. Maybe your issue could be resolve by upgrade flutter or switch channel.

Comment: I am using 1.12.13+hotfix.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can try appbar's elevation property as 0.0

```
AppBar(
elevation: 0.0,
),
```