# How to remove below line under appBar despite elevation set to 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove following blue Line underneath my appBar.

[image]

**What have I tried already?**

**1.** changing color of appBar `backgroundColor: kTextfieldBorderColor,`

**2.** I have set elevation to 0 `elevation: 0`

**3.** Reviewing this similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459692/how-to-remove-the-small-line-below-appbar) but it doesn't give any satisfactory answer but only a temporary solution. **edit:** I tried the solution mentioned here and it doesn't work by making both Scaffold and appBar transparent

[image]

**4.** I also tried adding `toolbarHeight: kToolbarHeight + 1.25,` to appBar and this even doesn't work.

Below am adding the complete Scaffold code, for you to get an idea why its causing this problem.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: kBackgroundColor,
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: kTextfieldBorderColor,
    elevation: 0,
    // leading: null,
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            //Implement logout functionality
            _auth.signOut();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }),
    ],
    title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    //Do something with the user input.
                  },
                  decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                  cursorColor: kTextfieldBorderColor,
                ),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  //Implement send functionality.
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Send',
                  style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Code of **constants** used for color, textField etc

```
const kBackgroundColor = Color(0xffEDD9C8);
const kRoundedButtonColor = Color(0xffC68E5D);
const kTextfieldBorderColor = Color(0xffC68E5D);
const kMessageTextFieldDecoration = InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
  hintText: 'Type your message here...',
  border: InputBorder.none,
);

const kMessageContainerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Please share colors, decorations and styles too (k*).

Comment: ok adding them, pls recheck

Comment: @carlosManta, I was the first to answer. No worries, glad your issue is resolved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with these line of codes...

```dart
const kMessageContainerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, width: 2.0),
  ),
);
```

and

```dart
Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
    ...
```

It's the container's border color.
You can change it to

```dart
const kMessageContainerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
  border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2.0),
  ),
);

// Or whatever you find it convenient.
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set **borderSide color** for Message container to **LightBlueAccent**. Change `kMessageContainerDecoration` BorderSide color to transparent.

```
const kMessageContainerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
border: Border(
    top: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent, width: 2.0),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Colors.transparent` as the background color for appbar and Scaffold.

Comment: I did this and have added image in my question in edits, it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not **appbar border** instead **textfield border**. If this happened you can check. */ Add Padding only top: 20 in the textfield /* I think it is impossible to have any border in the appbar. Or maybe even styled so that it appears in all cases in main. Cheer

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i tried it and blue line still remains :(